# Binary files in Scala

Tags: scala, file, outputstream

I want to create a binary file in scala that contain a list like this:

```
271,813854,270
271,814100,267
271,814106,813858
325,813854,324
325,814100,321
325,814106,813858
643,813854,642
643,814100,639
643,814106,813858
670,813854,813855
670,814100,666
670,814106,813858
```

In order to get this, I am writing the following code:

```
class Indexes (val listSPO:List[tripleInt], val listPSO:List[tripleInt], val listOSP:List[tripleInt] ){
  val sl = listSPO.sortBy(l => (l.sub, l.pre))
  val pl = listPSO.sortBy(l => (l.sub, l.pre))
  val ol = listOSP.sortBy(l => (l.sub, l.pre))

  var y1:Int=0
  var y2:Int=0
  var y3:Int=0

  val fstream:FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("patSPO.dat")
  var out:BufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fstream)
  val fstream2:FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("patPSO.dat")
  var out2:BufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fstream2)
  val fstream3:FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("patOSP.dat")
  var out3:BufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fstream3)

  for ( a <- 0 to listSPO.size-1){
    y1 = listSPO(a).sub
    y2 = listSPO(a).pre
    y3 = listSPO(a).obj
    val tpiSOP:tripleInt = new tripleInt(y1,y3,y2)
    out.write(tpiSOP)
  }}
```

Then each list contain a triple of Int numbers, And I want to create for each list a correspond file. the tripleInt object is declarate as:

```
class tripleInt(var sub:Int, var pre:Int, var obj:Int)
```

My question is why I am receiving an error in the line out.write(tpiSOP) and How I can fix it?

Update: The error is 'cannot resolve with such signature' 'Type Mismatch'

Comment: pls include the error / stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

The `write()` method doesn't know what a `tripleInt` is or what to do with it. You'll have to change `tpiSop` into something that the `write()` method understands, either a single `Int` or an `Array[Byte]`.

Comment: is it possible in convert the tripleint object in an Array[Byte]?

Comment: Well an `Int` is 32 bits (4 bytes) so you could translate 3 `Int`s into 12 bytes and fill an `Array` accordingly. A different option is just to write the 3 `Int`s one at a time.